# how to add all and remove all options in dual list box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to add and remove all options using the dual list box?

We are using one small dual list box, we want to add options left side to right side box, now
its work for single selected options moves to the right side but we also want all options to move to the right side even remove all options using button click.

and how to disable selected options, I mean restrict selected options?

Here is my **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/joelshah/hg5wLfn9/)**

Here is the sample code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnRight').click(function(e) {
    var selectedOpts = $('#lstBox1 option:selected');
    if (selectedOpts.length == 0) {
      alert("Nothing to move.");
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    $('#lstBox2').append($(selectedOpts).clone());
    //$(selectedOpts).remove();
    e.preventDefault();
    updateIDs();
  });

  $('#btnLeft').click(function(e) {
    var selectedOpts = $('#lstBox2 option:selected');
    if (selectedOpts.length == 0) {
      alert("Nothing to move.");
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    //$('#lstBox1').append($(selectedOpts).clone());
    $(selectedOpts).remove();
    e.preventDefault();
    updateIDs();
  });
});

function updateIDs() {
  $('#values').val('');
  $('#lstBox2 option').each(function(index) {
    console.log($(this).val());
    $('#values').val($('#values').val() + $(this).val() + ",");
  });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-sm-12">


  <div class="col-xs-4">
    Items to select
    <select id="lstBox1" style="width:40%" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" size=10>
      <option value="1">Test 1</option>
      <option value="2">Test 2</option>
      <option value="3">Test 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2" style="width:20%">
    <a id="btnRight" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Add</a>
    <a id="btnLeft" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Remove</a>
    <a id="btnRightall" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Add all</a>
    <a id="btnLeftall" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Remove all</a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4" style="width:40%">
    Selected Items
    <select id="lstBox2" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" size=10>

    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<input id="values" class="form-control" placeholder="Output IDs separated by commas here">
```

Comment: Do you want to keep the item on add in the original? And what do you mean by "and how to disable selected options, i mean restrict selected options?" Do you want the option to be unselectable once added?

Comment: @Mukyuu - yes restrict selected options, once selected the original option not allow to select 2nd time. exactly you thinking unselectable once added..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnRight').click(function(e) {
    var selectedOpts = $('#lstBox1 option:selected');
    if (selectedOpts.length == 0) {
      alert("Nothing to move.");
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    $('#lstBox2').append($(selectedOpts).clone());
    $(selectedOpts).remove();
    e.preventDefault();
    updateIDs();
  });

  $('#btnLeft').click(function(e) {
    var selectedOpts = $('#lstBox2 option:selected');
    if (selectedOpts.length == 0) {
      alert("Nothing to move.");
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    $('#lstBox1').append($(selectedOpts).clone());
    $(selectedOpts).remove();
    e.preventDefault();
    updateIDs();
  });
  $("#btnRightall").click(function(e) {
    var selectedOpts = $('#lstBox1 option:not([disabled])');
    if (selectedOpts.length == 0) {
      alert("Nothing to move.");
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    $('#lstBox2').append($(selectedOpts).clone());
    $(selectedOpts).remove();
    e.preventDefault();
    updateIDs();
  });

  $("#btnLeftall").click(function(e) {
    var selectedOpts = $('#lstBox2 option:not([disabled])');
    if (selectedOpts.length == 0) {
      alert("Nothing to move.");
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    $('#lstBox1').append($(selectedOpts).clone());
    $(selectedOpts).remove();
    e.preventDefault();
    updateIDs();
  })
});

function updateIDs() {
  $('#values').val('');
  $('#lstBox2 option').each(function(index) {
    console.log($(this).val());
    $('#values').val($('#values').val() + $(this).val() + ",");
  });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-sm-12">


  <div class="col-xs-4">
    Items to select
    <select id="lstBox1" style="width:40%" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" size=10>
      <option value="1">Test 1</option>
      <option value="2">Test 2</option>
      <option value="3">Test 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2" style="width:20%">
    <a id="btnRight" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Add</a>
    <a id="btnLeft" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Remove</a>
    <a id="btnRightall" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Add all</a>
    <a id="btnLeftall" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Remove all</a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4" style="width:40%">
    Selected Items
    <select id="lstBox2" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" size=10>

    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<input id="values" class="form-control" placeholder="Output IDs separated by commas here">
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s87b0v94/)

Once you cloned the item to the other side `.append($(selectedOpts).clone());`, you can simply remove them from the original container `$(selectedOpts).remove();`.

Answer (score 2):

As far as i understand, you want to add all the items from list1 to list2.

add this part of code

```
$('#btnRightall').click(function(e){
 $('#lstBox1 option').prop('selected', true);
 var selectedOpts = $('#lstBox1 option').prop('selected', true);
 $('#lstBox2').append($(selectedOpts).clone());
 e.preventDefault();
 updateIDs();
});
```

Here is the working example of what I tried:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnRight').click(function(e) {
    var selectedOpts = $('#lstBox1 option:selected');
    if (selectedOpts.length == 0) {
      alert("Nothing to move.");
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    $('#lstBox2').append($(selectedOpts).clone());
    //$(selectedOpts).remove();
    e.preventDefault();
    updateIDs();
  });

  $('#btnLeft').click(function(e) {
    var selectedOpts = $('#lstBox2 option:selected');
    if (selectedOpts.length == 0) {
      alert("Nothing to move.");
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    //$('#lstBox1').append($(selectedOpts).clone());
    $(selectedOpts).remove();
    e.preventDefault();
    updateIDs();
  });
  
  $('#btnRightall').click(function(e){
    $('#lstBox1 option').prop('selected', true);
     var selectedOpts = $('#lstBox1 option').prop('selected', true);
     $('#lstBox2').append($(selectedOpts).clone());
     e.preventDefault();
     updateIDs();
  });
  $('#btnLeftall').click(function(){
   var selectedOpts = $('#lstBox2 option').prop('selected', true);
    $(selectedOpts).remove();
    e.preventDefault();
    updateIDs();
  });
  
});

function updateIDs() {
  $('#values').val('');
  $('#lstBox2 option').each(function(index) {
    console.log($(this).val());
    $('#values').val($('#values').val() + $(this).val() + ",");
  });
}
```

```css
.col-lg-3 {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-sm-12">


  <div class="col-xs-4">
    Items to select
    <select id="lstBox1" style="width:40%" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" size=10>
      <option value="1">Test 1</option>
      <option value="2">Test 2</option>
      <option value="3">Test 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2" style="width:20%">
    <a id="btnRight" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Add</a>
    <a id="btnLeft" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Remove</a>
    <a id="btnRightall" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Add all</a>
    <a id="btnLeftall" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Remove all</a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4" style="width:40%">
    Selected Items
    <select id="lstBox2" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" size=10>

    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<input id="values" class="form-control" placeholder="Output IDs separated by commas here">
```

Comment: ohw! its working! but why this options clone to every time button click.. means if i select option and click add button for two or more times, the options come to append why?

Answer (score 2):

Please check this. And use `disabled` for restrict selected options?

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnRight').click(function(e) {
    var selectedOpts = $('#lstBox1 option:selected');
    if (selectedOpts.length == 0) {
      alert("Nothing to move.");
      e.preventDefault();
    }

   

var compar = $('#lstBox2 option');
  
  if($(selectedOpts).text() == $(compar).text()){
     alert("Nothing to move.");
     }
  else{
      $('#lstBox2').append($(selectedOpts).clone());
      e.preventDefault();
      updateIDs();
  }
  });

  $('#btnLeft').click(function(e) {
    var selectedOpts = $('#lstBox2 option:selected');
    if (selectedOpts.length == 0) {
      alert("Nothing to move.");
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    //$('#lstBox1').append($(selectedOpts));
    $(selectedOpts).remove();
    e.preventDefault();
    updateIDs();
  });
              
              $("#btnRightall").click(function(e){
                   var selectedOpts = $('#lstBox1 option:not([disabled])');
                  if (selectedOpts.length == 0) {
                      alert("Nothing to move.");
                      e.preventDefault();
                      }
                  $('#lstBox2').append($(selectedOpts).clone());
                  e.preventDefault();
                  updateIDs();
              });
              
                            $("#btnLeftall").click(function(e){
                                 var selectedOpts = $('#lstBox2 option');
                                if (selectedOpts.length == 0) {
      alert("Nothing to move.");
      e.preventDefault();
    }
                                $(selectedOpts).remove();
    e.preventDefault();
    updateIDs();
              })

              
});

function updateIDs() {
  $('#values').val('');
  $('#lstBox2 option').each(function(index) {
    console.log($(this).val());
    $('#values').val($('#values').val() + $(this).val() + ",");
  });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="col-xs-4"> Items to select
    <select id="lstBox1" style="width:40%" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" size="10">
      <option value="1"  disabled>Test 1</option>
      <option value="2">Test 2</option>
      <option value="3">Test 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2" style="width:20%"> <a id="btnRight" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Add</a> <a id="btnLeft" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Remove</a> <a id="btnRightall" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Add all</a> <a id="btnLeftall" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Remove all</a> </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4" style="width:40%"> Selected Items
    <select id="lstBox2" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" size="10">
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<input id="values" class="form-control" placeholder="Output IDs separated by commas here">
```

Comment: if i select option and click add button for two or more times, the options come to append why? i dont need it.. so can you correct me..

Comment: So don't use clone(); and if it solve your problem accept the answer.

Comment: bro i want clone(); but everytime button click its selected option cloned to right side box.. once selected  that will not allow to come again..

Comment: Ok Then you use compare for clone i am only done for add only Button. please check again..?

Comment: i saw ur answer bro! once i click add all button options move to right side, then i click remove all button the all options are deleted, its not revert (move back) to Left side box..

Comment: please check again as i said i done only for add button. Now check

Answer (score 1):

Hey try the below code and you can go through [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/praveen04/53to6jr1/4/) too.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnRight').click(function(e) {
    var selectedOpts = $('#lstBox1 option:selected');
    if (selectedOpts.length == 0) {
      alert("Nothing to move.");
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    $('#lstBox2').append($(selectedOpts).clone());
    //$(selectedOpts).remove();
    e.preventDefault();
    updateIDs();
  });

  $('#btnRightall').click(function(e) {
      var selectedOptsAll = $('#lstBox1  option').prop('selected', true);
    $('#lstBox2').append($(selectedOptsAll).clone());
    //$(selectedOpts).remove();
    e.preventDefault();
    updateIDs();
    });
    
  $('#btnLeftall').click(function(e) {
      var selectedOptsRemoveAll = $('#lstBox2  option').prop('selected', true);
    $(selectedOptsRemoveAll).remove();
    e.preventDefault();
    updateIDs();
    });
  $('#btnLeft').click(function(e) {
    var selectedOpts = $('#lstBox2 option:selected');
    if (selectedOpts.length == 0) {
      alert("Nothing to move.");
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    //$('#lstBox1').append($(selectedOpts).clone());
    $(selectedOpts).remove();
    e.preventDefault();
    updateIDs();
  });
});

function updateIDs() {
  $('#values').val('');
  $('#lstBox2 option').each(function(index) {
    console.log($(this).val());
    $('#values').val($('#values').val() + $(this).val() + ",");
  });
}
```

```css
.col-lg-3 {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-sm-12">


  <div class="col-xs-4">
    Items to select
    <select id="lstBox1" style="width:40%" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" size=10>
      <option value="1">Test 1</option>
      <option value="2">Test 2</option>
      <option value="3">Test 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2" style="width:20%">
    <a id="btnRight" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Add</a>
    <a id="btnLeft" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Remove</a>
    <a id="btnRightall" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Add all</a>
    <a id="btnLeftall" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Remove all</a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4" style="width:40%">
    Selected Items
    <select id="lstBox2" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" size=10>

    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<input id="values" class="form-control" placeholder="Output IDs separated by commas here">
```

Comment: if i select option and click add button for two or more times, the options come to append why? i dont need it.. so can you correct me..